# Dropdown menus don't work on some pages unless reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a sidebar that works with some js. To make it work I had to disable Turbolink directly inside the sidebar `data-turbolinks="false"`
For some reason I really don't get why I can't open the dropdown menu on some pages unless I reload the page...

For example I have no problem on the page below:

sales/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <% @sales.order('created_at DESC').each do |sale| %>
                <%= link_to admin_sale_path(sale) do  %>
                    <div class="small-cards">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <p><%= l(sale.created_at, format: '%d %B %Y' )%></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <p>Articles: <%= sale.count_articles %></p>
                                <p>Total : <%= number_to_currency_euro sale.total %></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I have problem on this one, I tried to add `data-turbolinks="false"`  in the container but it doesn't help.

categories/show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="primary_title"><%= @category.title.upcase %></h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="row">
            <% @category.products.each do |product| %>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <%= link_to clients_category_product_path(@category, product) do  %>
                        <%= render "shared/cards", product: product %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FYI: The shared partial contains some bootstrap carrousels

_sidebar.html.erb

```
<div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled" data-turbolinks="false">
    <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-brand">
          <a href="#">Main menu</a>
          <div id="close-sidebar">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
              <a href="#">
               <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
                <span>Order</span>
                <% if Order.where(status: "paid").count >= 1 %> 
                  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger"><%= Order.where(status: "paid").count %></span>
                <% end %>
              </a>
              <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to "Online sales", orders_path,  class: "list-item" %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>      
            </li>

            <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
              <a href="#">
               <i class="fas fa-truck"></i>
                <span>Sales</span>
              </a>
              <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to "Shop sales", sales_path,  class: "list-item" %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>      
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

app/assets/javascripts/sidebar.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
    if (
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .hasClass("active")
    ) {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideDown(200);
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
  });

  $("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
  });

});
```

Comment: I guess you are using `$(document).on('ready', function() {...` in your js code. Have you tried replacing it with `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...`?

Comment: Oh okay as I had disabled turbolink for the sidebar I thought I did not need to wrap  the js code in the `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...`

Comment: After wrapping the code as I suggested, it should work without disabling turbolink

Comment: It works only without turbolink...

Comment: My bad, I guess it would work if you change it to `on('click')`. At least that does the trick in my app

Comment: I did try `on('click')`but unfortunately it doesn't make the job...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
    if (
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .hasClass("active")
    ) {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideDown(200);
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
  });

  $("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh okay as I had disabled turbolink for the sidebar I thought I did not need to wrap its js code in the $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...
Thanks that works better :)

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: Yup it takes couple of minute to be allowed to accept :)